# Responsive label size

Tags: ios, text, uilabel

I'm working on my first app which is a simple quote generator. I have run into a couple of problems and I'm kind of out of my depth here (the freelancer I hired has done a half-baked job, and I'm trying to fix it myself now that I'm out of cash). Any pointers would be very helpful.

There is a list view of favourited quotes, and the space provided per quote is fixed - which looks odd when the quotes vary in size (there's either lots of empty space or the quote cuts off). I think the snippet below is where this can be amended, as it's where I changed the text alignment.

Also I made some edits to the text file which the app pulls the quotes from, but they are only sometimes reflected when the app is running in the simulator... This seems really strange that some of the edits work and some don't.

Any suggestions highly appreciated as I've tried everything I can think of through trial and error.

```
UILabel *favouriteLabel;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        favouriteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -10, 400, 140)];
    }else{
        favouriteLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -20, 160, 100)];
    }
    favouriteLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    favouriteLabel.text = [self.arrayFromFile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Row alloc %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Load label %@", favouriteLabel.text);
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        favouriteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Eras Bold ITC" size: 18];
    }else if([GUIHelper  isPhone5]){
        favouriteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Dosis-Medium" size: 14];
    }
    else
        favouriteLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Dosis-Medium" size: 14];
    favouriteLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    favouriteLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    favouriteLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    favouriteLabel.center = CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 40, cell.center.y + 20);
     favouriteLabel.tag = 900;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:favouriteLabel];

    UIImage *lineImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"quote-divider@2x.png"];
    CGRect lineImageFrame;
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        lineImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 110, lineImg.size.width, lineImg.size.height);
    }else{
        lineImageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 62, lineImg.size.width * 0.9, 0.8*lineImg.size.height);
    }
    UIImageView *lineImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:lineImageFrame];
    lineImageView.image = lineImg;
    lineImageView.center = CGPointMake(cell.center.x - 40, lineImageView.center.y + 35);
    // set the tag myImageView.tag = 1010;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineImageView];
```

Comment: The issue with the text file was resolved by uninstalling the app from the simulator, cleaning the project and running it again. Still stumped by the responsive list view however.